# Access to private attributes of class in C++

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I have two structs:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Cls {
    Cls(char c, double d, int i) : c( c ), d( d ), i( i ) {}
public:
    void getter() {
        std::cout << c << ' ' << d;
    }

private:
    char c;
    double d;
    int i;
};



struct B {
    B(char c, double d, int i) : c1( c ), d1( d ), i1( i ) {}
public:
    char c1;
    double d1;
    int i1;
};

char &get_c( Cls &cls )
{
    void *p = &cls;

    B *pb = static_cast<B *>( p );

    return pb->c1 = 'A';;
}

double &get_d( Cls &cls )
{
    void *f = &cls;

    B *fb = static_cast<B *>( f );

    return fb->d1 = 10;;
}

int main()
{
    Cls cls('h', 2.0, 3);
    char ch = get_c( cls) ;
    double dh = get_d(cls);
    std::cout << ch << ' ' << dh << std::endl;
    cls.getter();
}
```

As I know we can change private attributes of class `Cls` via class `B` and it works like Undefined Behaviour. But I can't understand why class `Cls` attributes depends of class `B`? I have read that it is related with their placement in memory like class `Cls` takes 24 bytes because of `c` takes 1 byte, then we have 7 empty positions, then `d` takes 8 bytes, then `i` takes 4 bytes, then 4 empty positions. But how it is affect on dependence of `Cls` attributes from `B` attributes?

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags. C is very different from C++

Comment: There is no dependency between `C1s` & `B` the behaviour is simply undefined and there's not much more to it as far as C++ is concerned. The program may produce any result it likes. However what probably happens in most cases is that both structs occupy the same amount of memory and the same layout -> so it may appear to do something expected.

Comment: @George but why they occupy the same amount of memory?

Comment: That's simply due to same memory layout of 2 structs. You could modify your private members by directly accessing memory of `Cls` struct instance. Like take address of struct, add 8 (1 byte for `sizeof(c)` and 7 bytes padding in front of `double d`) cast pointer to `double*` and by dereferencing that pointer modify `Cls::d` member.

Comment: @user3124812 As I understand, if I have `struct A` with address `0x1234` and I will create 100 more `structs` like `B, C, D, ...` address of all of them will be `0x1234`?

Comment: I think it is not the correct way of using the using class or struct. This might be working due to single program and limited data members. This will not work when you are performing big tasks. The concept you understood looks incorrect to me.
We have a friend-keyword for manipulating the private member of class from another class in C++, have a look at it.

Comment: @notamaster, of course not. `structs like B, C, D, ... address of all of them` and what do you mean by that ? do you distinguish type declaration and instantiation of variable of specific type

Answer (score 0):

There is no dependency of these two structs.

When structs are represented in memory their fields are placed one after the other from the object address.
The offset from the object's address of a field is know as its offset.

It's like

```
B *b = new b('A', 1337, 9);

//value of b is the address of the object
&b->c1 == b // true since c1 is first field
&b->d1 == b + 1 // since c1 is char and is 1 byte long
// Well not really thou since b + 1 is evaluated to (address of b + sizeof(b)) ie same as b[1];
// And what is really mean is (address of b + 1);
// To make the pointer arithmetic work we should first cast b to (void*) 
// Like this (void*)b + 1
&b->i1 == (void*)b + sizeof(c1) + sizeof(d1) // true since i1 comes after c1 that is 1 byte long and d1 that is another 8bytes long so offset of i1 is 0x1 + 0x8 = 0x9
```

The same applies for Cls and this is why you are getting the same fields.
Both structs have the same layout

Comment: To be honest, anyway I don't undestand about `Cls`. I understand about how fields of `B` represents in memory but I don't understand about the same layout. What do you mean as `same layout` and why are the same?

Comment: By the same layout I mean that the offsets of c, d, i are the same as the offsets of c1, d2, i1 even thou they are defined in different structs